# ObservableCollection data binding during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, calendar, observablecollection

I have a slight issue. I am making a calendar application with some listbox elements. Each calendar view retrieves it's "calendar events" from a dictionary where `TKey = DateTime` and `TValue = ObservableCollection <CalendarEvent>`. Now this works fine for any calendar day where there are predefined events already. I can data bind the listbox to a property that contains a reference to the dictionary entry of that particular calendar day. However another feature of my application should be the ability to add events during runtime. What I have done right now is, if there is no dictionary key present for that particular calendar day it just sets the Events property to null and then I change it during runtime if an event was added for that day, unfortunately it doesn't seem to like that, it doesn't "bind" properly or so to say.

Here is the code

```
    public CalendarDayView(DateTime date)
    {
        DataContext = this;
        Date = date;
        Events = CalendarRepository.Instance.Entries.ContainsKey(date) ? CalendarRepository.Instance.Entries[date] : null;
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CalendarEvent> Events { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method will set the listbox item source to the ObservableCollection if it hasn't been set already
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateItemSource()
    {
        if (Events == null)
            // This is the part that doesn't do anything unfortunately
            Events = CalendarRepository.Instance.Entries[Date];
    }
```

XAML markup

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CalendarDayView}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.2" Width="100" Height="100">
                        <Grid Name="contentGrid">
                            <ListBox 
                                Name="entriesListBox" Background="LightYellow" FontSize="10" 
                                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
                            </ListBox>
                        <!-- Date display below -->
                            <TextBlock 
                                Name="dateTextBlock" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMM}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you raising the `PropertyChanged` event anywhere to notify the view of binding changes. You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `CalendarDayView` model and raise the implemented `PropertyChanged` event in your property setters that are used as binding source (`Events` in this case).

The following code shows a simple example, but it might be better to add the `PropertyChanged` functionality to a base model class.

```
public class CalendarDayView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<CalendarEvent> _events;

    public ObservableCollection<CalendarEvent> Events 
    { 
        get { return _events; }
        set
        {
            _events = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Events");
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```